# iterate over vs iterate

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

Which one is correct or more correct?

1. These meetings get **iterated every** three weeks.
2. These meetings get **iterated over every** three weeks.

Edit: We are talking about a set of meetings (3-4 meetings) And they occur in pattern. This pattern occurs every 3 weeks.

More context? Scrum meetings:

1. Sprint planning meeting(once in 3 weeks)
2. Daily standup(daily)
3. Sprint Review Meeting(once in 3 weeks)
4. Sprint Retro(once in 3 weeks)

Comment: To iterate is to repeat; in data processing or some branches of mathematics, to iterate **over** a range of things is to repeatedly do something, in turn, to those things. Only (1) has the meaning 'these meetings happen every three weeks', which is, in fact, a better way of expressing it.

Comment: Yeah, saying the meetings "iterate" is not idiomatic in the US.  "Repeat" would be the normal term.

Answer (score 1):

The meetings may **happen, occur, come up**, or **are scheduled** as often as you please.

> An [iteration](https://www.lexico.com/definition/iteration) is more than a repeat—it is **one round of cycle**. You could call one pushup in a set of 15 an iteration.

While #2 is worse (meetings get iterated **over** every three weeks), the meetings in #1 may occur every three weeks, but with different content, not the very same content. So they don't iterate. Only in the film Ground Hog's Day would they iterate. Again.

Comment: I have edited the questions. meeting = 3-4 meeting sets. These meetings get repeated. Each meeting has a different purpose. Would this affect your answer?